# Install .ipa which certificate do I need

Tags: xcode, ipa

I have an `.ipa` file which I do not want to upload to the app store. I have uploaded it to a server so I can give users the link to download the `.ipa` and install on their device.

I have downloaded the file to a device, the file appears as a `zip` file.

What certificate do I need and how can I install the file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An *.ipa* file *is* a zip file, so there's nothing wrong there.

For people to be able to download and install an *.ipa* file, it needs to have been exported from the archive as an Ad Hoc distribution. This means that you have created a distribution profile for it that includes the device IDs of all the devices on which it is to be usable.

If you've done that, then the physical business of getting the file onto a device is pretty straightforward. A user can drag the file onto the device using iTunes, or using Xcode, or (this is the solution I find simplest and most reliable for ordinary users) using Apple Configurator.